# simulate dynamic response to laser impulse with TDDFT in SIESTA

Tags: siesta, td-dft, response-theory

I am trying to simulate the dynamic response of semiconductors to laser impulse, but I am not sure how to do it with TDDFT in siesta, I checked the [siesta-doc](https://docs.siesta-project.org/projects/siesta/tutorials/td-dft/index.html), and it seems I need to construct an excited state, and then begin TDDFT.
So How could I simulate the response to laser impulse?

Comment: I gave my +1 long ago, but I wonder if you've made any progress on this? It's now been 6+ months! Please update us :)

Comment: This is a terrific question and would be a terrific project...shame it hasn't been worked on